# Item is not being deleted from database when time is expired

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, model-view-controller, online-store

I am trying to make deal of the day feature in online store. I can make any product deal of the day, so I will give expiry time and date so that product is automatically removed from deal of the day table in data base. My js code is

```
   $.ajax({
 url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>public_controller/get_deals_of_the_day',
 method:'post',
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   let i;
   setInterval(function(){
     var today = new Date();
     var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
     var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

  for(i in data){
    var month = parseInt(data[i].expire_time.slice(0,2));
    var day = parseInt(data[i].expire_time.slice(3,5));
    var year = parseInt(data[i].expire_time.slice(6,10));
    var format = data[i].expire_time.slice(16,19);
    var hours = parseInt(data[i].expire_time.slice(11,13));
    if(format == 'PM' || format == ' PM'){
      hours = hours + 12;
    }
    // console.log(hours);
    var mins = parseInt(data[i].expire_time.slice(14,16));
    var cMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var cDay = today.getDate();
    var cYear = today.getFullYear();
    var cHours = today.getHours();
    var cMins = today.getMinutes();

            if (cDay >= day && cHours >= hours && cMins > mins) {
            let delId = data[i].product_id;
            console.log(delId);
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>public_controller/del_deal",
              method:"post",
              data:{delId: delId},
              success:function(){
                // alert('deal expired');
                // location.reload(true);
              },
              error:function(e){
                alert(e);
              }
            });
            }
   }

 }
  },1000);
```

});

what i am doing is that I am fetching data of deal of the day table from database as the homepage loads and checking every second either any product has reached it's expiry time. When products any products expires it send id to controller to delete product from deal of the table. My controller method is

```
  public function del_deal(){
$deal_id = $this->input->post('delId');
$deal = $this->db->where('deal_id',$deal_id)->join('products','products.product_id = 
deal_of_day.product_id')->get('deal_of_day')->row_array();
$update['price'] = $deal['old_price'];
$this->db->where('product_id',$deal['product_id'])->update('products',$update);
$this->db->where('deal_id',$deal_id)->delete('deal_of_day');
```

}

Condition is verifying I am just checking for day, hours and mins for testing purpose. Problem is it is not deleting product as conditions satisfies.
I making online store in codeigniter framework. I haven't made any feature like this before so if I am doing or if there is better way to do it please suggest me that would be so helpful.

Comment: This seems like a strange question.  You can absolutely can make an ajax call in the callback of the first ajax call, but not within the first ajax call and if it is an asynch ajax call then you can make another ajax call beside the first one.

Comment: ok i get what you are trying to say. can you point to the possible bug in this code that why it's not deleting product

Comment: Both request on the server will treated as a separate transaction and depending on how much time the first transaction takes to commit, you might have a race condition.

Comment: first ajax call is successful and second seems to work fine also but i am sending id to delete product but it's not being deleted

Comment: can you suggest a better way to make this feature

Comment: i am making second ajax call in success function or first call to i think first call is completed then second is made after specific condition is met

Comment: You should view your problem differently. Instead of sending a request to delete the deal of the day when it expires.  You should simply delete it in PHP when you get a request "get_deals_of_the_day" after checking if it has expired and not send it to the browser.  In the browser, you maintain the list of deals of the day and when one deal expires you delete it locally or mark it as expired.

Comment: After a refresh of the page it restarts whole over.

Comment: i am doing so.. means when  de al expires it shoudl be deleted from the database and when deleted page should be realoaded for that i can suer location.reload(). but problem is that i am sending product id to the controlle but product is not being deleted from the deal of the day table